# Reverse query order in ScyllaDB in version 5

Tags: scylla

I am having trouble finding a good up to date resource if reverse query orders are as bad as they were when Scylla started. Previously all rows needs to be read in memory and sorted before returning the result set when using a reverse query order.

However I was wondering if I should still worry about reverse query orders when using the latest Scylla version and doing reverse order queries on a single partition. I see that this issue was closed: https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/1413 and I read improvements in https://www.slideshare.net/ScyllaDB/scylla-summit-2022-scylla-50-new-features-part-1.

Should I still worry? Or should I still create materialized views to omit this problem (or other solutions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse queries are now only slightly slower than forward queries.

See https://www.scylladb.com/product/release-notes/scylladb-open-source-5-0/ for full details.